# What are the good alternatives for communication between local C++ and Java programs?

Tags: java, c++, sockets, communication, rpc

By "local" I mean both run in the same subnet, in most cases the same host/VM, therefore some standard cross-network cross-platform RPC mechanisms like SOAP, XML-RPC, CORBA, etc. seem unnecessary.

The payload is mainly numerical (mostly tabulated) data with some small amount of meta data (for example available data services, data description/type, etc.) from C++ to Java, and console/scripted UI events from Java to C++. So the C++ program acts like the server and Java program the client.

I can enumerate several options (mostly from searching this wonderful site) but I've never used or seen one in a real-world heavy-duty situation, so I really hope someone who's "been there, done that" can educate me about the pros and cons of the options.

1. Shared memory
2. Pipe, stdin/stdout, etc.
3. Custom data structure over plain socket (probably UDP) ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209406/interprocess-communication-between-c-app-and-java-app-in-windows-os-environment))
4. Messages over plain socket, could be Google protocol buffer, Thrift, JSON, etc. ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620115/c-and-java-objects-communication/3620177#3620177), among others)
5. Java RMI with C++ RMI server ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845730/java-rmi-communication-with-non-java-entity))
6. JNI (some answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463240/what-is-the-best-way-to-pass-information-from-java-to-c))

I'm pretty sure I've missed many options. Thank you all for your help!

---

Edited: I forgot to mention that performance is not a major concern as the data throughput is not expected to be huge (server is heavily database-bound), but it would be important to know if one option stands out to be much faster or slower. For example, I suppose nothing beats shared memory (if done right).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Options 3 and 4 are used in real-world heavy-duty situations.

Options 1,2,6 do not reach another host.

Option 5 is probably too troublesome for the non-Java side.

I'd go with Option 4, because Option 3 is too low-level (unless Option 4 turns out to be too slow). Choose your favourite cross-platform light-weight messaging protocol from the ones you enumerated. Those are all "battle-tested" and have libraries for most languages.

Comment: Thanks! As I said the two programs are very likely to be on the same host, so I'd greatly appreciate if you can elaborate on the same-host options as well. Regarding the messaging protocols, I know each one has pros and cons but do you have a favorite of your own?

Comment: As for same-host communication, I'd still go with Option 4 to localhost first, and only consider making it more complex if this turns out to be too slow.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with option 4.  I'd skip 5. 2 would be clunky.

We're talking passing the numerics as plain text, yes?

Comment: No, why? I certainly want to take advantage of protobuf's varint, for example.

Comment: Passing plain text is much easier to debug and process as it removes any weird binary format issues.  Text is a lot larger than binary of course, but you say your transaction rate is going to be relatively low.  I'd pass text of I could and only fall back to binary if I had to.

Comment: weird binary format issues should not be a problem when using an established wire format like protobuf.